# Convergence in cumulative distribution function implies weak convergence in multivariate case

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

We all know in $\mathbb{R}$, convergence in cdf on all continuous points implies weak convergence. That is, if a sequence of random variables $X_n: \Omega_n\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to +\infty}F_{X_n} = F_X$ (where $F$ is the cdf) on each point where $F_X$ is continuous for some random variable $X: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, then $X_n\Rightarrow^d X$. I am wondering if there is a multivariate analog on $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. It seems like if I define $F(x)$ be $P(x_1 \le x, x_2 \le x, ..., x_d\le x)$ (that is a cdf analog in $\mathbb{R}^d$), then the following holds: if a sequence of random variables $X_n: \Omega_n\to \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to +\infty}F_{X_n} = F_X$ on each point where $F_X$ is continuous for some random variable $X: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}^d$, then $X_n\Rightarrow^d X$. I tried to start from the theorem that if $X_n\Rightarrow^d X$, we can define an appropriate probability space that all $X_n$ and $X$ are defined on such that $X_n\to^{as} X$ i.e. the convergence is almost sure.

Comment: The result is true, but how to best prove it will depend on which equivalent characterization of weak convergence you are familiar with. Your approach gives you only the opposite direction, showing that weak convergence implies the convergence of the CDFs (they are still called this way in the multivariate case) at continuity points.

Comment: See page 196 of https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjonObP0ub7AhW4E1kFHYpfC7QQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1zF2wBS10F7yy1sBYoIHRu